# Report which generates all accounts with cases and opportunities

Tags: custom-reports

Condition: case opened date and Opportunity closed date difference on the account is less than or equal to 60 days.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Generally speaking, the community here likes to see that you've tried to solve the problem on your own before asking a question here. This can be done by sharing resources that you've looked at so far (external links, or links to other questions here on SFSE), sharing the current state of the code that you're developing (if applicable), etc... If you don't do that, it tends to make your question sound like a "do my work for me" request, which tend to be received poorly.

Answer (score 1):

A native Salesforce report cannot compare across child objects in the way you are seeking. In order to achieve this objective, you'll need to roll up date data from the Case and Opportunity objects to the Account.

Since Case is not available to form a native Roll-Up Summary field on Account, you'll need to figure out based on your business requirements how to achieve this objective. [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) is certainly only strong option.

Once your roll-up summaries have been established, you'll need to write a formula on the Account to compare the two fields based on your criteria, to return a checkbox perhaps or a status text. You can then report on your Accounts using that field as your criterion.